# Как вывести одинаковые значения элементов в зубчатом массиве?

Tags: c#, массивы

Например, создан массив массивов. Кол-во массивов вводит пользователь.кол-во элементов  им присвоено рандомно (5-20),значения тоже(0-500).Как вывести на консоль те значения,которые совпали хотя бы в двух массивах?
Код:

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите число массивов:");
            int numberOfArrays;
            numberOfArrays = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[][] array = new int[numberOfArrays][];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArrays; i++)
            {
                int valueOfElement = rnd.Next(5, 20);
                array[i] = new int[valueOfElement];
                for (int j = 0; j < valueOfElement; j++)
                {
                    array[i][j] = rnd.Next(0, 500);
                }
            }Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: что вы понимаете под "зубчатым" массивом?

Comment: @AK "рваный" массив.jagged array.Строки такого массива имеют разную длину.Массив массивов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку диапазон чисел очень невелик, проще всего создать "гистограмму" - массив `int H[501]`, обойти все массивы и помечать в H встреченные элементы

```
 обнулить H
 ...
 v = array[i][j]
 H[v] = H[v] + 1
```

И потом вывести индексы ненулевых элементов

Однако одинаковые элементы могут встретиться и в одном массиве, поэтому вместо счетчиков можно записывать номер массива

```
Заполнить H[] значением -1
...
v = array[i][j]
switch  H[v]:
     -1: H[v] = i             //первый раз, номер массива
      10000: ничего не делать //уже помечен
      else: H[v] = 10000       //второй раз - пометка
```

Comment: Почему массив, а не List или Dictionary?

Comment: Можно использовать и эти структуры, хуже не будет. По логике здесь map (dictionary). Для известного небольшого диапазона массив в качестве map работает хорошо - память перераспределять и хэши считать не нужно,